# timestamp delete hours and seconds

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

i have a timestamp 1390107800 is `Sun, 19 Jan 2014 05:03:20 GMT` How could get this date? `Sun, 19 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT`

I want any given timestamp add the first hour of the day it would be 00:00

thanks.

Comment: you tried X it failed because of Y. please insert the blanks

Comment: i tried 1390157566 Sun, 19 Jan 2014 18:52:46 GMT result is 1390107600 Sun, 19 Jan 2014 05:00:00 GMT WORNG !! why?? code : strtotime(date("Y/m/d 00:00:00",$timeStamp))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hard-code the zeros without issues but escape the GMT with back-slashes to make them literally show:

```
echo date('D, d M Y 00:00:00 \G\M\T', 1390107800);

// another option
echo date('D, d M Y', 1390107800).' 00:00:00 GMT';
```

For future reference: [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: having the date the convert timestamp to date and give the format with zeros and then back to timestamp. could not be done in a more elegant way? a greeting.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by more elegant. I mean this in all seriousness but are you looking for `echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', (1390107800 - SecretFormulaToSubtractSecondsToMidnight));`?

Answer (score 0):

Just hardcode the hours minutes and second..?

```
date("d/m/Y 00:00:00", $timestamp);
```